# Why debugger showing Twilio voice call incoming instead of outgoing in react native?

Tags: android, react-native, twilio

I am trying to integrate voice calling feature with Twilio. I use [react-native-twilio-programmable-voice](https://github.com/hoxfon/react-native-twilio-programmable-voice). I place call from my application to a mobile number which is verified in twilio account. But When i hear the call it is playing the TwilioML xml message and in debugger it is showing inbound call. It should be outbound call since I am calling from my application to another number.

Why this is happening? My application just need to call on other numbers. I don't want incomming call to application.

```js
TwilioVoice.connect({ To: +9196xxxxxxxx, From: '+14158959608' })
```

[image]

----- Update -----

XML updated to

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
    <Dial>+91969xxxxxxx</Dial>
</Response>
```

also used Twilio ML bin

[image]

But now showing error "**callerId must be provided for TwilioClient and SIP calls when using Dial**"

Where i made mistake ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A call from a Twilio client is inbound to Twilio. The Voice URL defined in your TwiML App is then interrogated to determine where to route the call. There are two call legs, the inbound leg from the client and the outbound leg to the dialed party which you need to construct in the TwiML. The TwiML will use the [Dial verb](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/dial) and [Number noun](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/number).

[Setting Up Call Forwarding](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223179908-Setting-Up-Call-Forwarding)

[How Does Twilio Client Pricing Work?](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223180608-How-Does-Twilio-Client-Pricing-Work-)

Comment: When I changed the voice xml and used Dial verb with the verified number it is giving error in debugger "callerId must be provided for TwilioClient and SIP calls when using Dial"

Comment: Set the callerId parameter of the dial verb, https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/dial#callerid, to either a Twilio number or verified CallerID.

Comment: I have change Twilio ML & used Dial & Number and it is started working. But still have query hope you will resolve it.
1. How to dynamically change the phone number to call on any number?
2. Currently restricted to verified caller id. Can I use any number after paid account?

Comment: Yes, after upgrading. Reference: Twilio Free Trial Limitations - https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/360036052753-Twilio-Free-Trial-Limitations